# Why is button element unaffected by CSS?

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with styling a button element. Here is the sample:

```
$clrWhite: #fff;
$clrPrimary: #3c9494;
.khanbank__button {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: $clrWhite;
    cursor: pointer;
    &--primary {
        background: $clrPrimary;
        &:hover {
            background: darken($clrPrimary, 5%);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the what i've tried:

[Test](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/GbEBvK)

Comment: The styles make sense for me and is working on test. Whats the problem ?

Comment: it's not working that height and border etc.

Comment: In future please include all relevant information **in the question itself**. That includes HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using [BEM](http://getbem.com/)

The issue is on your HTML, as you need to have both classes applied to the element

```
<button class="khanbank__button khanbank__button--primary">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/GbEBvK), you wrote:

```
<button class="khanbank__button--primary">Test</button>
```

However, if I were to translate your SCSS into normal CSS, it would become:

```css
:root {
  --clrWhite: #fff;
  --clrPrimary: #3c9494;
  --clrPrimaryDarken: #358282;
}

.khanbank__button {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: var(--clrWhite);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.khanbank__button--primary {
  background: var(--clrPrimary);
}

.khanbank__button--primary:hover {
  background: var(--clrPrimaryDarken);
}
```

```html
<button class="khanbank__button--primary">Test</button>
```

Perhaps now you could see the problem.

In your HTML you have only applied `.khanbank__button--primary` to `<button>`. You need to also apply the base class `.khanbank__button` to it.

In short, your HTML should be:

```
<button class="khanbank__button khanbank__button--primary">Test</button>
```

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjwpvw) for working example.